# How to use an input column as a major index in hierarchical indexing in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

My csv file contains columns such as:

```
col1   col2

1      0.9
1      0.3
2      0.4
2      0.9
2      0.1
3      0.0
4      0.5
4      0.9
```

And I put this into a data frame, so naturally the df adds an index to all of the rows.
I want to keep the first column as my major index, and within each major index, have a minor index such as:

```
ID       col1   col2

1      1        0.9
       2        0.3
2      1        0.4
       2        0.9
       3        0.1
3      1        0.0
4      1        0.5
       2        0.9
```

How do I do this?

My end goal is to be able to eliminate rows of a certain Major ID.  For example, if the average of the rows in Major ID 4, is below 0.5, then I'll eliminate those rows.

I assume the best way is to use a major index, but if there's a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can create the column `ID` from your `col1`, and then drop `col1`.

Then you can use `DataFrame.groupby` , on `ID` column, and then use [`.cumcount()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the result you want. Example -

```
df['ID'] = df['col1']
df = df.drop('col1',axis=1)
df['col1'] = (df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1)
```

Demo -

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   col1  col2
0     1   0.9
1     1   0.3
2     2   0.4
3     2   0.9
4     2   0.1
5     3   0.0
6     4   0.5
7     4   0.9

In [21]: df['ID'] = df['col1']

In [23]: df = df.drop('col1',axis=1)

In [24]: df['col1'] = (df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1)

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
   col2  ID  col1
0   0.9   1     1
1   0.3   1     2
2   0.4   2     1
3   0.9   2     2
4   0.1   2     3
5   0.0   3     1
6   0.5   4     1
7   0.9   4     2
```

After this, if you want `id` as the index, you can use [`.set_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method passing `'ID'` as the parameter.

Comment: This is cool!  thanks.  But, even if I add that index, using `set_index` as you said, how do I easily select all of the rows of that major index?  i.e., in my question, say I'd like to select all of the rows of major index `1`?